# How to build a endpoint with Spring to save large files not loading the entire file in memory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im modeling a generic endpoint to work with files (CRUD). Some files can have more than 1GB and i cannot stay with all this in memory, how to work with streams (up and down) those files to dont hold the entire file in memory?

I seen something to transform MultpartFile in a stream on the endpoint, but it's no clear if at this point the file already in memory.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot only the small files will be loaded to memory. A large file will be loaded to a temporary file. You should move that file to your desired location by calling `MultipartFile.transferTo()` method. Otherwise it will be eventually lost.

Please note: the default max file size is 10MB. You can increase it like this:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=200MB
```